# How to count the number of certain words appearing in a column (using countif and unique?)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have many entries that look like this.

[image: look like this]

I have taken a look at this for potential ideas to analyze what I have: https://www.statology.org/google-sheets-count-occurrences/

However, I don't know if I need to process this first by splitting the content into different cells (specifically the commas and "or"), or whether I should use a pivot table. Hence I'm posting a question here for some guidance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

`=QUERY(INDEX(PROPER(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"(?i)\sor\s",", ")),","))))),"Select Col1, COUNT(Col1) GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY COUNT(Col1) DESC LABEL COUNT(Col1) ''")`

-

[image]